# Is there an open-source implementation for graph convolution networks for weighted graphs?

Tags: python, resource-request, geometric-deep-learning, graphs, graph-neural-networks

Currently, I'm using a Python library, [StellarGraph](https://github.com/stellargraph/stellargraph), to implement GCN. And I now have a situation where I have graphs with weighted edges. Unfortunately, StellarGraph doesn't support those graphs

I'm looking for an open-source implementation for graph convolution networks for **weighted graphs**. I've searched a lot, but mostly they assumed unweighted graphs. Is there an open-source implementation for GCNs for weighted graphs?

Comment: You can take a look at "Diffusion Convolutional Recurrent Neural Network: Data-Driven Traffic Forecasting" (you can find it on Github). In there you can find an implementation of the diffusion convolution which is applied to a weighted graph, the traffic adjacency matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A Comprehensive Survey on Graph Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.00596) (2019) presents a list of ConvGNN's. All of the following accept weighted graphs, and three accept those with edge weights as well:

[image]

And below is a series of open source implementations of many of the above:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[Pytorch_Geometric](https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_geometric)** library for your projects. Its **supports weighted GCNs**. It is a rapidly evolving open-source library with easy to use syntax. It is mentioned in the landing page of [Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/). It is the most starred Pytorch github repo for geometric deep learning. Creating a GCN model which can process graphs with weights is as simple as:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv

class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(dataset.num_node_features, 16)
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(16, dataset.num_classes)

    def forward(self, data):

        # data has the following 3 attributes
        x, edge_index, edge_weight = data.x, data.edge_index, data.edge_weight

        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index, edge_weight)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index, edge_weight)

        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)
```

See [this](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/introduction.html) for getting started.
Check out its [documentation](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/nn.html#module-torch_geometric.nn.conv.message_passing) on different variants of GCNs for further details. One of the best thing is that like Pytorch, its documentation are self-sufficient.

Comment: Is there any reason why Pytorch Geometric wouldn't deal with negative weights in GCNConv()? When I use positive weights it works just fine. When I use negative ones it sometimes returns nans and causes problems. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Graph Attention Networks for weighted graphs. This model can handle negative weights. Check out its [documentation.](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/nn.html#module-torch_geometric.nn.conv.message_passing)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/22800)